# Building Open Source library Teem with Levmar support using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I try to build the library Teem under Windows 64bit with levmar support using cmakeGUI with generator VisualStudio10 Win64.

First off all, i built Levmar with CLAPACK and F2C. That works fine as levmar can be compiled without errors and the demo succeds.

The mysterious thing is, when i try to build teem with levmar support ON, cmake always turns it off "because it was not found" although i told cmake the path to levmar.lib.

Thats what the CmakeGUI tells me:
"warning: Turning off Teem_LEVMAR, because it wasn't found.
Configuring done"

Here is a part of  my CMakeList.txt delivered with teem:

```
# Look for "levmar" library <http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/>
option(Teem_LEVMAR "Build Teem with levmar library support." OFF)
set(Teem_LEVMAR_LIB "")
if(Teem_LEVMAR)
  find_package(LEVMAR)

  if(LEVMAR_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DTEEM_LEVMAR)
    set(Teem_LEVMAR_LIB ${LEVMAR_LIBRARIES})
    set(Teem_LEVMAR_IPATH ${LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR})
  else()
    # We need to set this as a cache variable, so that it will show up as
    # being turned off in the cache.
    message("warning: Turning off Teem_LEVMAR, because it wasn't found.")
    set(Teem_LEVMAR OFF CACHE BOOL "Build Teem with levmar library support." FORCE)
  endif()
endif()
```

Has anyone an idea what happens here?

I tried the same thing with 3 different levmar.lib and different generators but unfortunately i suggest that i have to tell cmake the exact name of the library or the name levmar.lib is simply wrong.

I reported that question also to my supervisor for my thesis but he had the same problem and could not help me.

I also tried to modify the CMakeList:

```
#if(Teem_LEVMAR)
  include_directories(${LEVMAR}/lib)
#endif()
```

which was originally

```
if(Teem_LEVMAR)
  include_directories(${Teem_LEVMAR_IPATH})
endif()
```

but it did not help.

Why does cmake recognizes levmar.lib not as the levmar library, in fact does not accept it.
i also tried to understand why `find_package(levmar)` does not succeed but now i do not know any ways to make it work.

greetings,
jan luca.

Comment: Judging from [FindLEVMAR.cmake](https://github.com/CIBC-Internal/teem/blob/master/CMake/FindLEVMAR.cmake), you need to set both `LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR` and `LEVMAR_LIBRARY`, did you do that?

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked. i still do not understand why setting the path in the cmakeGUI did not worked but that is not quite important. I set a environment variable LEVMARLIB and wrote $ENV{LEVMARLIB} in the cmake file and now cmake finds the levmar lib. THANKS

Comment: @m.s. Would you mind to make an answer from your comment? This way Jan can accept it and the question is marked as answered.